# Trying to build a queue for Next js 13 with custom api ( bull, next.js, redis)

Tags: node.js, redis, next.js13, bull

Hi developers i am trying to work on queue in next.js 13 with a custom api.

This is how far I got... the api is working the connection to redis is working but the middle is not working im trying to build the queue to learn and to grow for my personal project.

I'm stuck for 3 days now I did 1 script 2 script and a 3 script use that I just cut it in pieces, still no luck so I try my luck here.

im getting the following error:

```
Error: No .lua files found!
    at loadScripts (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/bull/lib/commands/index.js:29:15)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/bull/lib/commands/index.js:18:19)
✅ Redis Connected Successfully
```

api/temp/route.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const Queue = require('bull');
import { connectToRedis } from "@/lib/redis";

export async function createQueue() {
  const redis = await connectToRedis();
  const queue = new Queue('my-queue', { redis: { client: redis, }, });
  return queue;
}

export async function addJob(queue, job) {
  await queue.add(job);
}

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    const queue = await createQueue();
    await addJob(queue, { name: "John", age: 30 });
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello, redis, bull API" }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "An error occured by creating a que."}, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

second try:

```
const Queue = require('bull');
import { connectToRedis } from "@/lib/redis";

export async function createQueue() {
  const redis = await connectToRedis();
  const queue = new Queue('my-queue', { redis: { client: redis, }, });
  return queue;
}

export async function addJob(queue, job) {
  await queue.add(job);
}
```

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Queue from "bull";
import { createQueue, addJob } from "@/lib/queue";

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    const queue = await createQueue();
    await addJob(queue, { name: "John", age: 30 });
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello, redis, bull API" }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "An error occured by creating a que."}, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I tried google the awnser, read all the website off the used software but still no luck at all.

Comment: Hey !
Did you manage to solve the issue ? I'm having the same one here ...
Thanks !

Comment: Yes I did figure out a solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with bull. but we made a switch to bullmq with a spin off using a redis with handling temporary jobs.

Comment: can you post your answer here? see [how i always post it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034626/6141587). helps future developers (possibly you in case you forget) with the same problem.

Comment: I will make time this weekend to post a small solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get background jobs working with Next.js is by using the experimental `instrumentation`.

Docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation

Edit:
Instrumentation showed itself to not be fit for this kind of task at the moment. I will leave this answer here to keep the comments in case someone finds them useful.

Comment: I did it different, but thank you. I got it working !

Comment: @Redbeardjunior i would love to know how you got it working?

Comment: where's the blog post? its giving 404

Comment: I have it working on a different base line you could hit me up and try to explain.

Comment: @Redbeardjunior i did hit you up on github (same username?) but you probably forgot to get back to me with a solution. i'm just curious how to keep the worker running in next.js? do i have to use instrumentation like others suggest?