# Cannot find package 'drizzle-orm' in Docker Container even though I do npm install in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, sqlite, npm

I install all my dependencies in Dockerfile using `npm ci` below.

##### Dockerfile

```bash
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# 1. Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
COPY /src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# 2. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY . .

# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY .env.production .env.production
RUN mkdir -p /data

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

# Create /data/users.prod.sqlite using Volume Mount
# RUN npm run db:migrate:prod
RUN npm run build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

# Move the drizzle directory to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

# Move the run script and litestream config to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder /app/scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs
COPY --from=builder /app/scripts/init.sh ./init.sh
COPY --from=builder /app/scripts/run.sh ./run.sh
RUN chmod +x init.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh


USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000


CMD ["sh", "run.sh"]
```

##### run.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# npm run db:migrate:prod & PID=$!
# Wait for migration to finish
# wait $PID

echo "Starting production server..."
node server.js & PID=$!

wait $PID
```

When I do `docker-compose up`, I get this error:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'drizzle-orm' imported from /app/scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs

My `package.json` contains these 2 scripts:

```json
 "db:migrate:prod": "node --env-file .env.production ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs"
 "start": "next start",
```

I also checked `docker run -it easypanel-nextjs npm list` & got this:

```bash
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: @epic-web/remember@^1.0.2, required by easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: @t3-oss/env-nextjs@^0.9.2, required by easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: drizzle-orm@^0.29.3, required by easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: jiti@^1.21.0, required by easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: std-env@^3.7.0, required by easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: tsx@^4.7.1, required by easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0
npm ERR! missing: zod@^3.22.4, required by easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0
easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0 /app
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @epic-web/remember@^1.0.2
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @t3-oss/env-nextjs@^0.9.2
+-- better-sqlite3@9.4.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/better-sqlite3@9.4.1/node_modules/better-sqlite3
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY drizzle-orm@^0.29.3
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY jiti@^1.21.0
+-- next@14.1.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next
+-- react-dom@18.2.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom
+-- react@18.2.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY std-env@^3.7.0
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY tsx@^4.7.1
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY zod@^3.22.4
```

How do I solve this error?

I even tried using [anonymous modules](https://michalzalecki.com/docker-compose-node/) but those didn't work either.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
    # depends_on:
    #   db:
    #     condition: service_healthy
    #   redis:
    #     condition: service_started
    image: easypanel-nextjs
    container_name: nextjs-sqlite
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - /app/node_modules
  # migration:
  #   build:
  #     context: .
  #     dockerfile: docker/migrations/Dockerfile
  #   image: easypanel-nextjs
  #   depends_on:
  #     web:
  #       condition: service_completed_successfully
```

My container gets stopped with this error:

```bash
> easypanel-nextjs-sqlite@0.1.0 db:migrate:prod
> node --env-file .env.production ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs

node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
        ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'drizzle-orm' imported from /app/scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:910:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1130:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

When I try to go inside a stopped container using `docker run -it easypanel-nextjs sh` & do `ls node_modules`, then I get this:

```bash
/app $ ls node_modules/
better-sqlite3  next            react           react-dom
```

Only 4 dependencies. My `package.json` has lots of dependencies:

```json
{
  "name": "easypanel-nextjs-sqlite",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "turbo": "next dev --turbo",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "knip": "knip",
    "clean": "rimraf .next",
    "db:push": "drizzle-kit push:sqlite",
    "db:generate": "drizzle-kit generate:sqlite",
    "db:migrate": "node --env-file .env.development ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs",
    "db:seed": "node --import tsx --env-file .env.development ./scripts/seed/insert.ts",
    "db:delete": "node --import tsx --env-file .env.development ./scripts/seed/delete.ts",
    "db:migrate:prod": "node --env-file .env.production ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@epic-web/remember": "^1.0.2",
    "@t3-oss/env-nextjs": "^0.9.2",
    "better-sqlite3": "^9.4.1",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.29.3",
    "jiti": "^1.21.0",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "std-env": "^3.7.0",
    "tsx": "^4.7.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/better-sqlite3": "^7.6.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.19",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.20.14",
    "knip": "^5.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

What is the issue?

I have a full reproduction -> https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite

Comment: Does deleting the `volumes:` block in the Compose file help?  Your `node_modules` tree is coming from an anonymous volume and not the image, which can lead to problems like this.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze but i figured it out just now on my own after a week. [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034626/6141587). i think it was a combination of chown (right permissions on node_modules), anonymous volumes, installing all production dependencies & then removing them using `--prune` & a bunch of other things. i'd love if you can answer how can i make `make start-production` faster as it currently does `pnpm install` & takes 60 seconds at least. i've mentioned the question below at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Latest answer (USE THIS)

I had to create a new `package.json` with just Drizzle Migration dependencies.

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "scripts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "better-sqlite3": "^9.4.3",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.29.4",
    "std-env": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I also removed `node_modules` from the final image as it wasn't required anymore. This reduced the image size a lot down to just 175mb.

I removed `prod-dependencies` FROM-block from Dockerfile so it simplified it a bit.

And copied `scripts/package.json` to install dependencies from it.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# mostly inspired from https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults/blob/main/Dockerfile & https://github.com/remix-run/example-trellix/blob/main/Dockerfile

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@8.15.4 --activate 
# set the store dir to a folder that is not in the project
RUN pnpm config set store-dir ~/.pnpm-store
RUN pnpm fetch

# 1. Install all dependencies including dev dependencies
FROM base AS deps
# Root user is implicit so you don't have to actually specify it. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553149/6141587
# USER root
USER node
# WORKDIR now sets correct permissions if you set USER first so `USER node` has permissions on `/app` directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY --chown=node:node package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
COPY --chown=node:node /src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

USER root
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline

# 2. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps --chown=node:node /app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY --chown=node:node .env.production .env.production

# Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867550/6141587
USER root
# Give /data directory correct permissions otherwise WAL mode won't work. It means you can't have 2 users writing to the database at the same time without this line as *.sqlite-wal & *.sqlite-shm are automatically created & deleted when *.sqlite is busy.
RUN mkdir -p /data && chown -R node:node /data

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN pnpm build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
USER node
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME '0.0.0.0'
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/static ./.next/static

# Move the drizzle directory to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

# Move the run script and litestream config to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/package.json ./scripts/package.json
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/pnpm-lock.yaml ./scripts/pnpm-lock.yaml
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/run.sh ./run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh

CMD ["sh", "run.sh"]
```

I install the only needed dependencies for migration here.

#### run.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Only install dependencies for drizzle migration. Those are not bundled via `next build` as its optimized to only install dependencies that are used`
echo "Installing production dependencies"
cd scripts
pnpm config set store-dir ~/.pnpm-store
pnpm fetch
pnpm install --prod --prefer-offline
cd ..

echo "Creating '/data/users.prod.sqlite' using bind volume mount"
pnpm run db:migrate:prod & PID=$!
# Wait for migration to finish
wait $PID

echo "Starting production server..."
node server.js & PID=$!

wait $PID
```

#### New answer

I removed the `pnpm install` from `run.sh` that was slow to boot container (`docker compose up`) up. So the 1 minute wait went away. And I copied `node_modules` with production dependencies in the final stage which made my image go from 198mb to 611mb but that's okay for me.

Then I tried adding SQLite WAL mode which resulted in data loss due to networking issue. Idk why that doesn't work properly but its neither Docker's fault nor my Volume syntax was wrong. So I commented out WAL mode & everything works fine now.

The new solution uses security best practices in Node.js by using non-privileged users. And the solution is much cleaner & simpler to understand.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nextjs-sqlite
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

#### Dockerfile

```bash
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# mostly inspired from https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults/blob/main/Dockerfile & https://github.com/remix-run/example-trellix/blob/main/Dockerfile

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@8.15.3 --activate 
# set the store dir to a folder that is not in the project
RUN pnpm config set store-dir ~/.pnpm-store
RUN pnpm fetch

# 1. Install all dependencies including dev dependencies
FROM base AS deps
# Root user is implicit so you don't have to actually specify it. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553149/6141587
# USER root
USER node
# WORKDIR now sets correct permissions if you set USER first so `USER node` has permissions on `/app` directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY --chown=node:node package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
COPY --chown=node:node /src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

USER root
RUN pnpm install

# 2. Setup production node_modules
FROM base as production-deps
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps --chown=node:node /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN pnpm prune --prod

# 3. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps --chown=node:node /app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY --chown=node:node .env.production .env.production

# Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867550/6141587
USER root
# Give /data directory correct permissions otherwise WAL mode won't work. It means you can't have 2 users writing to the database at the same time without this line as *.sqlite-wal & *.sqlite-shm are automatically created & deleted when *.sqlite is busy.
RUN mkdir -p /data && chown -R node:node /data

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN pnpm build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
USER node
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME '0.0.0.0'
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/public ./public
COPY --from=production-deps --chown=node:node /app/node_modules ./node_modules

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/static ./.next/static

# Move the drizzle directory to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

# Move the run script and litestream config to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/run.sh ./run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh

CMD ["sh", "run.sh"]
```

#### run.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Creating '/data/users.prod.sqlite' using bind volume mount"
pnpm run db:migrate:prod & PID=$!
# Wait for migration to finish
wait $PID

echo "Starting production server..."
node server.js & PID=$!

wait $PID
```

#### Original answer (DO NOT USE THIS)

The reason for this was my `node_modules` didn't exist when I went into `run.sh` or atleast it only had a few folders that I mentioned above so I figured I should `npm install` them in `run.sh` & that's what I did.

I actually changed to `pnpm` as I thought it would be fast. Idk if it actually is fast on my docker but it is definitely fast locally.

I also used permissions like chown as I learned its a Node.js best practice.

And finally, I used `node_modules` as an anonymous volumes courtesy of https://michalzalecki.com/docker-compose-node/

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: easypanel-nextjs
    container_name: nextjs-sqlite
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - /app/node_modules
```

#### Dockerfile

```bash
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# mostly inspired from https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults/blob/main/Dockerfile & https://github.com/remix-run/example-trellix/blob/main/Dockerfile

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@8.15.3 --activate 
# set the store dir to a folder that is not in the project
RUN pnpm config set store-dir ~/.pnpm-store
RUN pnpm fetch

# 1. Install all dependencies including dev dependencies
FROM base AS deps

# Root user is implicit so you don't have to actually specify it. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553149/6141587
# USER root
USER node
# WORKDIR now sets correct permissions if you set USER first so `USER node` has permissions on `/app` directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY --chown=node:node package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
COPY --chown=node:node /src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

USER root
RUN pnpm install
USER node

# 2. Setup production node_modules
FROM base as production-deps
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN pnpm prune --prod

# 3. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps --chown=node:node /app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY --chown=node:node .env.production .env.production
RUN mkdir -p /data

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN pnpm build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/public ./public
COPY --from=production-deps --chown=node:node /app/node_modules ./node_modules

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/.next/static ./.next/static

# Move the drizzle directory to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/src/app/db/migrations ./migrations

# Move the run script and litestream config to the runtime image
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /app/scripts/run.sh ./run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["sh", "run.sh"]
```

#### run.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Installing dependencies using pnpm..."
pnpm install & PID=$!
wait $PID

echo "Creating 'data/users.prod.sqlite' using bind volume mount"
pnpm run db:migrate:prod & PID=$!
# Wait for migration to finish
wait $PID

echo "Starting production server..."
node server.js & PID=$!

wait $PID
```

The full working version is at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite/

The only caveat right now is when I start the container, it takes time because it is doing `pnpm install`.

I'd love to figure out how to make it so that it doesn't have to `pnpm install` every time I do `make start-production` in my project. I use `Makefile` which you can check at the linked repo.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run `pnpm install` in the `run.sh` script; you already install packages in your Dockerfile.  Make sure to delete the `volumes:` line that hides the image's `node_modules` tree, so that you're using the libraries that are built into the image.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze, initially i used it because i got error i posted `cannot find package 'drizzle-orm'`, i think after i copied `node_modules` that contains prod dependencies in `runner` stage fixed it. so i tried your suggestion & i think it works well. please confirm what i'm saying is correct even though the image size increased from 198mb to 611mb because of production dependencies. anyway to reduce that at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze i tried your solution & for some reason, my database is not syncing using volume mount. for example, i deleted `./data` folder locally & it did get deleted from `/data` location but my app still runs without errors & data is still there. i couldnt find `*.sqlite` file anywhere else in my container. have no idea where `.sqlite` is stored or if it is using another image. i have 2 images (`docker images`) but only 1 container is running (`docker ps`). any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @DavidMaze so i figured out that the error i faced was neither with docker or the way i used volumes but sqlite. turns out, the wal mode in sqlite doesn't work well wth network file-systems which resulted in data loss. it works fine if i disable the wal mode so i guess i did just that. gonna update the answer now, thanks!